# Make file download to folder instead of downloads folder .net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have the following method which when clicked from a forms action link will automatically open PDFS and Images in a new browser window. How can I download all other files to the following path on my PC. C:\Temp

```
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Download(int DocumentRepositoryID)
    {
        var documents = await CustomerFleetManagementService.ViewDocumentAsync(DocumentRepositoryID);
        return File(documents.ImgData, documents.ImgContentType);
    }
```

Comment: You can't, that's the browser's responsibility. Imagine downloading to the Startup directory or overwriting the kernel.

Answer (score -3):

The following code gets a document from the API it then creates a path in the clients C: with a folder called Temp2.

FileStream then creates a file with whatever filename you want. E.g. documents.ImgName = "ABC.docx"

A new stream is then opened where I am passing a byte array, zero (0) as default index and the length of the file.

ProcessStartInfo then opens the file from the folder Temp2 automatically without the end user manually having to open the file.

```
 [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Download(int DocumentRepositoryID, int customerID)
    {
        var documents = await CustomerFleetManagementService.ViewDocumentAsync(DocumentRepositoryID);
        
        string path = @"C:\Temp2";
        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
        FileStream stream = new FileStream(Path.Combine(path, documents.ImgName), FileMode.Create);
        stream.Write(documents.ImgData, 0, documents.ImgLength);
        stream.Close();
        new ProcessStartInfo(@"C:\Temp2\"+documents.ImgName).StartProcess();
        return RedirectToAction("Files", "Customer", new { customerID = customerID });
    }

  public static class UT
    {
            public static Process StartProcess(this 
            ProcessStartInfoo psi, bool useShellExecute = 
            true)
    {
        psi.UseShellExecute = useShellExecute;
        return Process.Start(psi);
    }
    }
```

Comment: Code only answers are not accepted. Please add comments and explanations.

Comment: Furthermore your backend code will execute on the server only.

Comment: This will only work if client and server are on the same machine. Ie the file will be saved on the server in path `c:\temp2\...` and not on the client.

Comment: @derpirscher so if I deploy this .net core application to IIS and anyone who visits the website and navigate to the Download actionresult will the directory not be created on the client machine.

Comment: How can I create folder in client machine.

Comment: @Tappas No, this code runs on serverside. You cannot create any folders on the client side. Where the user stores a downloaded file is totaly his own decision. Assume, some macos or linux client accesses your page. What will they do with a path like C:\temp ?